# how to match db column data type time without time zone with time string '03:15:00' in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have column with datatype time without time zone in postgresql . so i want to match time store in this colum with string '03:15:00'
I have written the foll. query

```
 select * from table1 
 where to_timestamp(timecol)::timestamp without time zone
       = to_timestamp('03:15:00')::timestamp;
```

here the column name with data type time without time zone is 'timecol'

can any one tell me how to match the above fields.

Comment: Rephrasing your question:

*How do I find all rows where the time part in `timecol` is `'03:15:00'`, ignoring the date part entirely*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rephrasing your question:

*How do I find all rows where the time part in `timecol` is `'03:15:00'`, ignoring the date part entirely*?

For this you can just compare with a `TIME` value, because when you compare a `TIME` to a `TIMESTAMP` the `TIME` gets automatically extended to have the same date as the `TIMESTAMP`.

e.g.

```
select * from table1
where timecol = CAST('03:15:00' AS time)
```

In more complex cases you would use `date_trunc` and/or `extract` functions.